# Trying to create a material design like textbox, issue in input validation

Tags: css, html, material-design

I am trying to create a material design inspired textbox.

I have read similar questions/answers around. However, my question is little different, so kindly read on.

Here is my stylesheet for the page -

```
.textBoxContainer{
height:50px;
position:relative;
margin:20px;
}

.textbox{
    border-bottom: solid 2px #984343;    
    border-top: none;
    border-left: none;
    font-family: Candara;
    width: 30%;
  }

.textbox + .lbl{
position:absolute;
top:0px;
left:0px;
transition:all .2s ease-out;
}

.textbox:focus{
 border-bottom: solid 2px #4CAF50;
  outline:none;    
}

 .textbox:focus + label, input:valid+label{
 top:-15px;
 font-size:10px;
 }
```

Here is the textbox which I am trying to create -

```
<div class='textBoxContainer'>
<input class='textbox' type="text" />
<label class='lbl'>
phone no....
</label>
</div>
```

It works fine like a material design inspired textbox, where the text moves up upon typing.

However, after the typing is done, if I move out of the textbox, then the label collapses back again on the textbox.

I was thinking 'input:valid' will help prevent it from happening, but it did not.
I can solve this with javascript, but is there a way around without using js?

I have also tried this putting a 'required' in the input filed, that did not help either.

Please let me know if I should explain any further.

Comment: I updated your answer. But its not the answer (I already knew the js answer) I was looking for, so I am not accepting this as an answer

Comment: No problem. Thanks!

Comment: I mean I have already upvoted your answer.

Comment: Figured that's what you meant. All good.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that would require to use javaScript. If you don't want to use javascript, just keep the label on top of the textField, or just use a placeholder.

The way to implement it using JavaScript that would be as follows:

Add a `onfocusout` event listener to all the textfields which you want that label to stay up.

```
<input class='textbox' type="text" onfocusout="leaveFocus(event)" />
```

Next, you have to create the function which gets called everytime the textField looses focus.

```
function leaveFocus(event) {

    const textField = event.target;
    // Check if textField is empty
    if (textField.value !== '') {
        textField.classList.add('has-text);
    } else {
        // Otherwise, textFiled has text
        textField.classList.remove('has-text);
    }
}
```

That function checks to see if the textField is empty. If it is, it removes the class of `has-text`, and if it has text, it adds the class of `has-text`.

Now in your `css`, you have to add `has-text` to all the styling you have for the label going up, like this:

```
.textbox:focus, .has-text{
     border-bottom: solid 2px #4CAF50;
     outline:none;    
}

 .textbox:focus + label, .has-text + label, input:valid+label{
     top:-15px;
     font-size:10px;
 }
```

Let me know if this answers your question, and let me know if you need any more help.